# My Bitcoin wallet is out of sync after connecting for the first time

Tags: synchronization

It's 4 years out of date. I have tried using a different network. Same thing. Don't know what to do but would appreciate help.

Comment: P.S. Please don't pad out your question. The minimum character limit is there for a reason: questions that are under it usually don't provide enough details, and have been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

The official Bitcoin software has to download the details of every single address, transaction and confirmation block to be synchronised. If you've just installed it then it's going to take you 1-5 days to download that data depending on your Internet and computer speed (just leave it running on your computer).

There are other options to avoid this but as a rule of thumb it's more secure to use a "full client" such as the official software. Once it has sync'd every time you use it after that it will only need to sync the data since it last sync'd so is much, much quicker.